# "Conosciuto da lui personalmente": si può esprimere in un modo più naturale?

Tags: word-usage

Cercando di scrivere qualcosa su Giovanni Verga, mi è venuta fuori questa frase:

> Durante un soggiorno a Parigi nel 1884, dove incontrerà Edmond de Goncourt e anche Émile Zola, **conosciuto da lui personalmente** nel 1882 in un precedente viaggio nella capitale francese, continuerà a lavorare su questo suo libro.

Ho usato il grassetto per sottolineare l'espressione che mi causa confusione, in cui ho usato *conosciuto* per non ripetere il verbo *incontrare*. Non sono per niente sicura che questa espressione suoni bene agli orecchi di un madrelingua. Infatti, una ricerca su Google di "conosciuto da lui personalmente" pochissimi risultati. Quindi, la mia domanda è, sarebbe un modo di riscrivere la frase in modo che sembri più naturale? O andrebbe bene così?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La frase non è sbagliata e si può usare, però a me suona piuttosto pesante e burocratica (in particolare con quel *da lui*), me la vedo più in un modulo di un ufficio che in uno scritto di letteratura.

È pesante anche perché poi la frase è lunga, diventa faticosa.

È una questione di stile, e come tale ha una componente soggettiva, non ci si può riferire a regole o divieti di usarla: mi sembra brutta, tutto qui.

Quindi sono d'accordo con te che sarebbe meglio cambiarla.

Scriverei semplicemente *che aveva conosciuto personalmente nel 1882...*

Comment: Concordo, e in più propongo di togliere anche l'avverbio (“che aveva conosciuto nel 1882...”), in quanto il cenno al precedente viaggio chiarisce comunque che si erano visti di persona.